# reactjs - communication between two components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call a function from one component to another. I've tried a few different things after googling, but as I'm new to reactjs I can't seem to work it out. I thought I could import the state and then change it from the other component (see below) but I think I'm barking up the wrong tree?

I want to call `showMenu()` in header.js from locationform.js

header.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactF1 from 'react-f1';

// Styles.
import styles from './Header.css';

// Elements.
import Menu from './elements/Menu';

// Menu states.
import { states, SHOWBUTTON, IDLE, HIDE, OUT } from './elements/Menu/states';

import transitions from './elements/Menu/transitions';

function changeOffset() {
  document.querySelector('svg path').style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
  setTimeout("document.querySelector('svg path').style.strokeDashoffset = 171", 2000);
}

export default class Header extends Component {
  static get propTypes() {
    return {
      children: PropTypes.element,
    };
  }

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      menuState: OUT,
      hamburgerState: OUT,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.router.location.pathname === '/') {
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({ hamburgerState: SHOWBUTTON }), 6000);
    } else {
      this.setState({ hamburgerState: SHOWBUTTON });
    }
    // setTimeout(changeOffset, 8000);
  }

  completeF1Handler() {}

  showMenu() {
    this.setState({ menuState: IDLE });
  }

  hideMenu() {
    this.setState({ menuState: HIDE });
  }

  reset() {
    this.setState({ menuState: OUT });
  }

  render() {
    const { stageWidth, stageHeight } = this.props;

    return (
      <ReactF1
        className={styles.Header}
        go={this.state.hamburgerState}
        states={states(stageWidth, stageHeight)}
        transitions={transitions()}
        onComplete={() => this.completeF1Handler()}
      >
        <svg className={styles.hamburger} data-f1="hamburger" width="50" height="50">
          <path
              className={styles.triangle}
              d="M0 0 L50 0 L0 50 Z"
              onClick={this.showMenu.bind(this)}
              fill={this.props.menuColor}
          />
        </svg>
        <Menu
          go={this.state.menuState}
          close={this.hideMenu.bind(this)}
          reset={this.reset.bind(this)}
        />
      </ReactF1>
    );
  }
}
```

locationform.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { isDesktop } from '../../utils/device';
import LocateSelect from '../LocateSelect';

import styles from './LocationForm.css';
import buttonStyles from '../Button/Button.css';

// Menu states.
import { states, SHOWBUTTON, IDLE, HIDE, OUT } from '../Header/elements/Menu/states';

export default class LocationForm extends Component {
  static get propTypes() {
    return {
      zipCode: PropTypes.string,
      searchRadius: PropTypes.string,
      businessType: PropTypes.string,
      handleChange: PropTypes.func,
      handleGeolocate: PropTypes.func,
      handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
    };
  }

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }



  showMenu() {
    console.log("show menu");
      this.setState({ menuState: IDLE });
  }

  renderSelect() {
    const { searchRadius, businessType, handleChange } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={styles.selectContainer}>
        <LocateSelect
          id="searchRadius"
          defaultValue=""
          value={searchRadius}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          options={[
            {
              value: '',
              text: 'SEARCH RADIUS',
            },
            {
              value: '1',
              text: '1 MI',
            },
            {
              value: '5',
              text: '5 MI',
            },
            {
              value: '10',
              text: '10 MI',
            },
            {
              value: '25',
              text: '25 MI',
            },
          ]}
        />
        <LocateSelect
          id="businessType"
          defaultValue=""
          value={businessType}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          options={[
            {
              value: '',
              text: 'BUSINESS TYPE',
            },
            {
              value: 'bar',
              text: 'Bar',
            },
            {
              value: 'restaurant',
              text: 'Restaurant',
            },
            {
              value: 'liquorstore',
              text: 'Liquor Store',
            },
          ]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const {
      zipCode,
      handleChange,
      handleSubmit,
      handleGeolocate,
      handleFocus,
      handleBlur,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className={styles.LocationForm} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="button"
          className={`${buttonStyles.Button} ${buttonStyles.dark} ${styles.geolocate}`}
          value="Use Current Location"
          onClick={handleGeolocate}
        />
        <p>OR</p>
        <input
          id="zipCode"
          type="text"
          placeholder="ZIP CODE"
          value={zipCode}
          maxLength="5"
          pattern="[0-9]*"
          onFocus={handleFocus}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          onChange={event => handleChange(event.target.id, event.target.value)}
        />
        {this.renderSelect()}
        <input
          className={`${buttonStyles.Button} ${buttonStyles.dark}`}
          type="submit"
          value="search"
        />
          <div className={buttonStyles.Button} onClick={() => this.showMenu()}>
              No
          </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear, which function do you want to be accessible in locationform?

Answer (score 4):

With considering parent child communication in react you have to write a parent for both of these files and passing the function and the state as props .

For example :

app.js

```
import Header from './header.js'
import LocationForm from './location-form.js'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {menuState : 'out'}
  showMenu() {
    this.setState({ menuState:'idle' });
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Header showMenu={this.showMenu} menuState={this.state.menuState}/>
        <LocationForm showMenu={this.showMenu} menuState={this.state.menuState}/>
      </div>
    )
  }  
}
```

I think this concept of thinking will help you to reach the answer

Comment: I'm after a quick fix as this site only has 2 more weeks before it gets rebuilt :/ Maybe making them inherit is the quickest solution (which doesn't seem that quick). Dirty hacks are fine as well though?

Comment: @colouredFunk I think writing dirty code will waste your time more than the coding in the right way. and also i thing 2 weeks is enough for every site to rebuilt . I can help you wherever you need :)

Answer (score 0):

So in react in order to pass data from parent to child elements you need to pass them down as props

So using your Menu component as an example you would pass the methods you want to use down to that child component like this: (I would recommend converting those to es6 syntax so you don't have to bother with binding).

```
//METHODS SECTION
const showMenu = () => {
    this.setState({ menuState: IDLE });
  }

  const hideMenu = () => {
    this.setState({ menuState: HIDE });
  }

  const reset = () => {
    this.setState({ menuState: OUT });
  }

//IN YOUR RENDER METHOD
<Menu
          go={this.state.menuState}
          close={this.hideMenu.bind(this)}
          reset={this.reset.bind(this)}
          showMenu={this.showMenu}
          hideMenu={this.hideMenu}
          reset={this.reset}
        />
```

Then in your child component you would refer to that method as this.props.showMenu or this.props.hideMenu or this.props.reset:

```
onClick(() => {this.props.showMenu()})
```

If you want the method to fire on an event you should wrap it in an anonymous function like I did above. You can also add it to another method within the child component that will get called when that method is called so:

```
const doSomething = () => {
   count++
   this.props.showMenu()
}

onClick(() => {this.doSomething()})
```

When you use the method in the child component it is still bound to the parent component. This is the main way of sending data back up to the parent. You could, for instance, have the method simply setState of a value on the parent component, pass the method down to the child as props with parameter requirements, pass the parameters in on the child and send it back up to parent when it is called. (Let me know if that was confusing)

There is a lot in your app that isn't very "React" so I would definitely recommend going through their documentation. Starting with: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html and watching some videos on Youtube about state management in React.

Answer (score 0):

Communication between parents is best thought of as having two methods of operating:

1. Parents can pass their children props
2. Children can call functions which are passed to them from their parents

This means that the relationship between components is defined via. their props. It's a one way method of communication that makes it much easier to build components as detached modules that *happen* to be connected in a given context.

So if you have something like:

```
         Child A
       /
Parent
       \
         Child B
```

Then you need to communicate via. the `Parent`. The children will call a function given to them by their parent, and the parent will pass down a new prop to the child components.

You can also do this thing via [`context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), which allows you to avoid having to pass all of these props down manually, but does not affect the streams of communication available to components.

```js
const ButtonComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Child
      <button onClick={props.handleClick}>
        Do the thing
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const CountDisplay = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{props.count}</div>
  );
};

const Parent = (props) => {
  const parentLog = () => console.log('log from parent'); 
  const [
    currentCount,
    setCurrentCount,
  ] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      Parent
      <ButtonComponent handleClick={() => setCurrentCount(currentCount + 1)} />
      <CountDisplay count={currentCount} />
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```